# Locking feature service without affecting its map service

Tags: arcgis-server, map-service, security, feature-service

Is there a way to lock a feature service published by ArcGIS Server. For example: When I publish a service with feature access capability, I get two URLs; one for a map service, and the other for the feature service, but when going to the manager to lock the feature service, I can lock the map service, which locks both (the map and feature service). Is there any idea to lock the feature service only and keeping the map service unlocked?

[image]

[image: Locking the service in the manager]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Feature service is really imho a poor naming issue. The map service has a capability named Feature Access which makes it possible to access a map service with Feature Access capability enabled on the source data level.

When you apply permissions to a map service, it is applicable for this service regardless of what capabilities this service has enabled.

Comment: I have the following scenario: Two groups of users will have access to the service; the first group is our native editors who edit the data using the service, and the other group is other users from other institutions who want to plug the service in their web mapping apps and are not allowed to edit the data. I am looking for a solution that enables editing only by our editors, and the other users only read the data. Do you have any idea?